# coredata file is not pulled from remote repository

Tags: ios, git, core-data

I pushed my code to repository, I can see the `MyProject.xcdatamodel/contents` file in bitbucket along with other files. But when pulling the repository, all files are added except the coredata file `MyProject.xcdatamodel/contents`. Am I versioning the right coredata files? Thanx.

**EDIT:**

here is my gitignore file:

```
.DS_Store
*.swp
*.lock
profile
DerivedData/
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
#    NB: also, whitelist the default ones, some projects need to use these
!default.pbxuser
!default.mode1v3
!default.mode2v3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcuserdata
!xcshareddata
!xcschemes
*.moved-aside
*.xcodeproj
.xcworkspace
```

Comment: What's in your ignore file?

Answer (score 0):

**Ignoring files**

From time to time there are files you don't want git to track. There are a few methods of telling git what files to ignore.

If you create a file in your repository named `.gitignore` git will use its rules when looking at files to commit. Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a rule was added to this file to ignore it. In such a case the file must be un-tracked, usually with git `rm --cached filename`

This file can be committed into the repository, thus sharing the rule list with any other users that clone the repository.

Note that you can create a `.gitignore` in any subpath to have its rules applied at that path. Sometimes an empty `.gitignore file` is used as a placeholder for an empty path, for example to force git to generate a log/ path for your development environment to use.

Example `.gitignore` file

```
*.exe
*.dcu
*.dres
*.local
*.identcache
__history/*
Win32/*
Win64/*
```

Answer (score 0):

As standard, I'd setup the ignore file as:

```
xcuserdata
project.xcworkspace
.DS_Store
```

And add from there as required.

Not sure why you'd want to add `*.xcodeproj` into your ignore file. This is the main repository of project information. Whenever you add files the the project (like adding a model version) you want the change to be recorded in the project...

There are some things inside the xcodeproj file (it's really a folder) that you can ignore, but you shouldn't ignore the whole thing.